# Копирование части экрана с помощью Javascript

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Доброго времени суток! Хотел бы узнать, можно ли средствами HTML5, Javascript и CSS3 сделать копию определенной части экрана, в независимости что там расположено (картинка, текст и т.д)?

Comment: Имеется ввиду скриншот?

Comment: Или вы хотите воссоздавать копию содержимого одного браузера в другом?)

Comment: Да, скриншот ограниченной части экрана)

Answer (score 3):

Да, можно. Для таких целей исползуйте вот этот плагин: http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/ Единственное ограничение - он не скриншотит iframe с другого домена по соображениям безопасности.

Comment: Спасибо. Пригодилось, единственная проблема, не копируются изображения. И хотелось бы узнать, есть возможность поиграть с z-индексом, чтобы разные слои копировались

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я знаю, нельзя сделать непосредственно скриншот. То что предложил @Дмитрий-Новиков (html2canvas) - эта библиотека парсит и рисует на canvas дом, т.е. по сути выполняет работу браузера по отрисовке страницы.

Надо учитывать, что скриншот полученный по этому методу может отличаться от настоящей страницы (не только картинками).

Также если политика безопасности браузера не дает доступа к фрейму - то и фрейм может быть отрисован.

Comment: Скриншот в виде изображения, в принципе, может и не потребуется, если получится найти параметры, при которых библиотека отрисует и изображения в том числе. Суть в том, что мне нужно достигнуть эффекта размытости заднего фона, но все упирается в большом количестве элементов, на которые нужно накладывать дополнительные стили. Поэтому возникла идея делать скриншот перекрываемой части и размывать его

Comment: Интересная идея) Но есть проблема, если картинка которая была добавлена на канвас была на другом домене, то вызов `toDataURL` для сохранения изображения вызовет ошибку из-за политики безопасности. Возможно причина в этом. Еще возможно вы не дожидаетесь загрузки изображений, хотя тут я не уверен.

Comment: Изображение грузится с поддомена этого же сайта. Посмотрю что будет если прямой путь указывать